# Validating the existence of a remote directory in C#

Tags: c#, directory, exists

I am using [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) to see if an entered directory is a valid directory. This works well for all local directories, and for valid remote directories that I have access to, but for remote directories that I don't have access to, it is slow to invalidate.

I suspect that this is because of a built in set number of attempts to find the directory, which are all failing because I don't have access to it.

How can I determine a remote directory is invalid faster?

Comment: What kind of "not have access to" is it that you have? Missing ACL? Remote path not shared? Server down?

Comment: @Lasse Remote path not shared.

Comment: Can you enumerate which ones are, and is that faster than trying to access the one you're having problems with?

Comment: @Lasse Can you point me toward how I can do that? I've been running with opening a command prompt in the background and using [net use](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) to log into the remote directories - I don't really know how I can check to see if I have permissions.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea if you can do it, or how to do it, I'm just asking questions. However, Windows can show open shares on a remote server so I assume it is possible, but I don't know if that is faster than trying to connect to a share that isn't there in the first place.

Comment: @Lasse I think that sounds like a good place to start digging - Iterating through a list of directories to see if I have access has got to be faster than waiting for a Directory.Exists call to timeout.

Comment: Well, it depends on the exact behavior here. If trying to connect to the share is like the teacher in the Ferris Bueller movie (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NP0mQeLWCCo), I'd imagine just running down the isles and noting the names of everyone present, and comparing that to who was supposed to be there would be quicker. But as I said, I really have no idea, it might be that is equally slow, or perhaps slower, depending on the number of shares open.

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly different approach, it may be worth giving [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2fzb02.aspx) a try, internally it may use a different approach than Directory.Exists():

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(yourPath);
if(di.Exists())
{
    ...
}
```

But watch out, the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo.aspx) seems to throw exceptions in some cases.
Since this is not a static class, it may perform even worse, but it's worth trying I'd think.